# How to count space in a text statement in PHP

Tags: php, text, count, spaces

How can we count space between text in PHP?

```
example: hi how are you?

spaces: 3
```

Is there a way to count spaces?

Language: Only PHP

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use this:

```
substr_count($text, ' ');
```

Comment: What if a string has two spaces between two words?eg "New  World".

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

```
$numSpaces = preg_match_all('/[ ]/', $testStr, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = count_chars($str,1);
echo $arr[32];
```

Comment: This way still works, but it's really a round-about way, since the substr_count() function exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text   = "Biography of the author of Riyād al-Sālihīn";

$spaces = substr_count($text,' ') ?: 0; // if override spaces from sentences

$data   = substr($text,0,$length + $spaces); //`enter code here
```