# Check if string contains 2 spaces (but not one after the other)

Tags: php, regex

How would You check if string contains exactly 2 non-adjacent spaces in PHP ?

f.e. 'John Wayne Washington' -> TRUE (2 spaces in string);
'John Wayne' -> FALSE (1 space)

Any regex pattern with explanation ?

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Have you tried anything looking into any tutorials?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php. Also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034017/how-to-count-space-in-a-text-statement-in-php

Comment: Anyway, the regex is `^[^ ]* [^ ]+ [^ ]*$` and it should be computationally similar to the function suggested by @WiktorStribiżew (edited: the OP's searching for 2 not-adjacent spaces)

Comment: Ah, the title contains the details in parentheses: *(but not one after the other)*. Then right, `str_count` will not help.

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = "Bush      sucks       big    time";
$counter = count_chars($string,0);
echo $counter[32] . " spaces in the phrase.";
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation alongside a code chunk so that others with a similar question can easily understand what is happening. As it stands now, this question is in a low quality posts review queue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern:

```
^[^ ]* [^ ]+ [^ ]*$
```

It matches a string with exactly 2 non-adjacent spaces.